# mysql: too many connections with max connection set to 500

Tags: mysql

For some reason I am having a problem with too many connections. I close my connections when I am done with them.

After the connections pool hits 100. I get the "too many connections" error and it closes the current connection.

When I run the command show proccesslist, it show 100 connections, but when I run "show variables like 'max_connections'" it shows the max connections is 500.

My questions is why, why am I getting this error when my max connections are set to 500? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do changes in "my.cnf",
max_connections = 500

Note : if this line is not in my.cnf then add this line.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL 5.7 you find the configuration file under: `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7`. Which is `my.ini`. Edit it and set the write parameter for connections number, as:

```
# The maximum amount of concurrent sessions the MySQL server will
# allow. One of these connections will be reserved for a user with
# SUPER privileges to allow the administrator to login even if the
# connection limit has been reached.
max_connections=500
```

Answer (score 0):

For some versions of MySQL, there is apparently an `open_file_limit` that can overrided the `max_connections` limit.  Also note the this can also be affected by `ulimit -n`.

See http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/12/increasing-mysql-55-maxconnections-on.html for more details.